# HBase: Efficiently list the columns for a given row that match a given prefix

Tags: hbase

I'm trying to use the HBase Java client to answer the following question as efficiently as possible:

> For a given row and a given column family, which qualifiers have a certain prefix?

I'd likely use a `QualifierFilter` with a `BinaryPrefixComparator`.  Would this work?  My intuition is that it should be possible to do this without sending the corresponding cell contents of those columns, right?  Would something like a `KeyOnlyFilter` work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I got to work.  `KeyOnlyFilter` works splendidly, as does `ColumnPrefixFilter`, which as far as I can tell is equivalent to `QualifierFilter` and `BinaryPrefixComparator`.

```
Scan scan = new Scan(MY_ROW, getSuccessor(MY_ROW))
                .addFamily(MY_COLFAM)
                .setMaxVersions(1)
                .setFilter(
                    new FilterList(
                        Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, Arrays.<Filter>asList(
                            new KeyOnlyFilter(),
                            new ColumnPrefixFilter(MY_PREFIX)
                        )));
```

Where `getSuccessor()` is a function that merely adds a null byte to the end.